# Convert Azure desired state configs (DSC) powershell scripts to JSON or YAML

Tags: json, azure, yaml, dsc

Convert Azure desired state configs (DSC) PowerShell scripts to JSON or YAML

Is there a way to do convert DSC .ps files to json or yaml.

I am trying to covert DSC first to python but that is also not direct possible.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Converting Desired State Configuration (DSC) PowerShell scripts directly to JSON or YAML is not a straightforward automated process because DSC scripts and JSON/YAML serve different purposes. DSC scripts define the desired state of a system using a specific PowerShell syntax, while JSON and YAML are data serialization formats. However, you can manually create JSON or YAML representations of the configuration data defined within a DSC script. This process involves interpreting the configuration elements within the DSC script and representing them in JSON or YAML format.

For example-
First, you need a DSC configuration defined in a `.ps1` file.

```
Configuration MyWebServer {
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'PSDesiredStateConfiguration'
    Node localhost {
        WindowsFeature IIS {
            Ensure = "Present"
            Name   = "Web-Server"
        }
    }
}

Write-Host "MyWebServer configuration has been loaded."
```

[image]

Run the configuration script to generate a `.mof` file. This `.mof` file represents the desired state in a standardized format that DSC can understand.

[image]

To convert the DSC configuration to JSON, you need to extract the configuration data. However, **DSC configurations do not natively support exporting directly to JSON or YAML**. As a workaround, you could define the configuration data as a hashtable and export it to JSON.

Let's assume we've modeled our DSC configuration data like so:

```
#ConfigurationData.ps1
$ConfigurationData = @{
    AllNodes = @(
        @{
            NodeName                    = 'localhost'
            PSDscAllowPlainTextPassword = $true
            PSDscAllowDomainUser        = $true
        }
    )
    WindowsFeature_IIS = @{
        Ensure = 'Present'
        Name   = 'Web-Server'
    }
}


#Convert the configuration data to JSON
$json = $ConfigurationData | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5

#Save the JSON
```

[image]

Now, convert this hashtable to JSON using the `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet in PowerShell. This will create a `MyDscConfiguration.json` file with your configuration data.

[image]

[image]

Now if you further want to convert this json to yaml then PowerShell does not have a built-in cmdlet to convert JSON to YAML, but you can install a third-party module called `powershell-yaml` to accomplish this.

[image]

After you've installed the `powershell-yaml` module, the next steps are to import the module, convert the JSON content to YAML, and save it. Run the below commands , just modify the path as per your own

```
# Import the powershell-yaml module
Import-Module powershell-yaml

# Path to the JSON file
$jsonFilePath = "C:\Users\arko\Downloads\MyDscConfiguration.json"

# Read the JSON file content
$jsonContent = Get-Content -Path $jsonFilePath -Raw

# Convert the JSON content to a PowerShell object
$object = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $jsonContent

# Convert the PowerShell object to YAML
$yaml = $object | ConvertTo-Yaml

# Path to the YAML file
$yamlFilePath = "C:\Users\arko\Downloads\MyDscConfiguration.yaml"

# Save the YAML content to a file
$yaml | Out-File -FilePath $yamlFilePath
```

you will end up with a `MyDscConfiguration.yaml` file in your directory wherever you have given the path.

[image]